# How To Run Firebase Queries In An Isolate In Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-isolates

Am trying to upload files to Firebase storage in an isolate but it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the following exceptions:

```
E/flutter ( 1527): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
E/flutter ( 1527): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:118:5)
E/flutter ( 1527): #1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:52:41)
E/flutter ( 1527): #2      FirebaseFirestore.instance (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:43:21)
E/flutter ( 1527): #3      new ForumsProvider (package:trumate/src/providers/forums.provider.dart:31:41)
E/flutter ( 1527): #4      CommonProvider.videoPost (package:trumate/src/providers/common.provider.dart:100:29)
E/flutter ( 1527): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1527): #5      CommonProvider.backgroundVideoUpload (package:trumate/src/providers/common.provider.dart:112:5)
E/flutter ( 1527): #6      FlutterIsolate._isolateInitialize.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart:128
```

Am using flutter_isolate: ^1.0.0+14 plugin for that. But it seems running Firebase queries inside the isolate is the issue.

My main has `await Firebase.initializeApp();` so I don't know I am getting such error.

Comment: if you put some code will be better to understand your problem.

Comment: Did you import the google-service.json to your project folder ? And maybe you should test if it works without isolate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isolates in Flutter are completely, well, *isolated*. Think of it a little bit like processes (in the sense that two isolates *share (almost) no memory*), instead of the traditional threads in Java or C in the sense of memory sharing.

Therefore, if you init your Firebase in your main isolate (as what you did in `main`), Firebase will not be inited in your other isolates. Thus, try to init it again in your other isolates.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter_isolate: ^2.0.2


onPressed: () {
  FlutterIsolate.spawn(_isolateEntrypoint, "foo");
}

// A "top level" function (i.e. not inside a class or make it static)
_isolateEntrypoint(String foo) {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    ...
}
```

Make sure that authorization and initialization were made on the same main thread (top level or static).
Now this FlutterEngine will be able to communicate with Firebase storage.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and wasn't able to run Firestore within an isolate.
I ended up using a Timer to handle it:

```
_MyAppState() {
  _timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) async {
   //Call function that handles firestore
   var upload = await fireUpload();
   //Returns value to despose timer if job is completed
   if (upload == false){
     dispose();
   }
  });
}

//Kills the Timer function
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: thats not whats the op asking